# Can you block an ip with multiple connections? (Apache ddos attack)

Tags: apache-2.2, ssh, firewall, ddos

My server is under a Apache ddos attack right now. There's a ton of single ip addresses with 30+ connections.

When I use this SSH command:

```
netstat -n | grep ':80' | awk -F' ' '{print $5}' | awk -F':' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

I'm getting this:

```
     30 69.144.146.74
     31 190.216.242.195
     31 92.20.224.127
     34 24.127.224.73
     37 197.34.29.122
     37 85.225.133.82
     38 108.29.62.196
     38 86.95.44.115
     40 66.62.146.84
     40 94.123.91.147
     46 24.117.238.91
     48 70.112.112.127
     48 71.58.158.150
     48 75.65.172.192
     51 99.127.238.167
     52 99.98.74.66
     53 107.7.34.66
     54 95.238.27.3
```

I've black listed over 100 ip's already, but within 5 min. there's all new ip's with 50+ connections.

I have no idea what to do right now. Is there a way to only allow a ip address to have 1 connection at a time? Or, is there a firewall that can protect against this thing? I'm freaking out here, how can this be fixed? Thanks.

Comment: iptables can handle this. You may be seeing a [slow loris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris) attack, which is fairly easy to mitigate these days.

Answer (score 1):

There are hardware / firewalls that can do this.  Your option at the apache level is a feature called "throttling".  There used to be a module for this, but it seems it's been removed.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467183/throttling-requests-by-ip-address-on-apache

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the severity, but you can always attempt to use [mod_evasive](http://systembash.com/content/how-to-stop-an-apache-ddos-attack-with-mod_evasive/) or [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/). Those are software firewalls that each do different things to react in case of an attack. If you are being attacked right now, I would recommend using `mod_evasive` right away since it's easier to understand than `mod_security` and very configurable from the get go. `mod_security` is a much better long term solution, but you might need to spend a lot of time configuring it properly so it doesn't get in the way of expected behavior on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Check out fail2ban and maybe review your iptables rules.

[fail2ban](http://www.dedmeet.com/software-projects-mainmenu-12/fail2ban-to-limit-ddos-attacks-on-webserver.html) is a traditional, widely used and supported tool to address your situation and similar.  It will blacklist IPs that are attacking you by (depending upon how you've set it up) adding a special chain to iptables and auto populating drop rules for attacking IP addresses.